# Tensorflow sporadically does not engage GPUs: only solution is to uninstall anaconda and tensorflow and reinstall but why does this happen?

Tags: graphics, gpu

My question involves very few details, so it may not be answerable unless you have experienced this problem.

Relatively frequently, I find that my installation of tensoflow-gpu does not engage the GPU during training of a model. It seems quite random in its occurrence but when it happens, the only solution I have is to uninstall anaconda and tensorflow and reinstall them again. If I run a GPU-burn, then the GPUs are engaged - it seems to be a particular problem for tensorflow.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, are they aware of why this happens?

Comment: Are you using proprietary drivers for your graphic card?

Comment: Michal, I'm using CUDA and I have 4 NVIDIA 1080ti cards